# Reseting a variable value everyday at midnight in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-schedule

I have a global var in my node js code. I need to reset its value to 1 everyday midnight at 12am. How is it done in node js?
I have read certain articles about node scheduler. Does it work or there are any other ways?

Comment: PM2 (recommended to run node in production) has a cron schedule function. I'd write the logic in a separate script and figure out a way to share the variable with your app (using api, file, redis or websocket maybe)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `setTimeout()` to schedule it yourself:

```
let myVar = 10;

function scheduleReset() {
    // get current time
    let reset = new Date();
    // update the Hours, mins, secs to the 24th hour (which is when the next day starts)
    reset.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0);
    // calc amount of time until restart
    let t = reset.getTime() - Date.now();
    setTimeout(function() {
        // reset variable
        myVar = 1;
        // schedule the next variable reset
        scheduleReset();
    }, t);
}

scheduleReset();
```

Any time your program starts, it can just call `scheduleReset()`.

FYI, I lifted most of this code from a program I wrote (on a Raspberry Pi server) that restarts itself at 4am every night and that program has been doing that successfully for several years.

Answer (score 0):

Using `node-schedule` this should be straightforward. Define your job with the [correct cron-tab](https://crontab.guru/every-night-at-midnight) and reset the variable to the default value in the `scheduleJob`-callback:

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
let yourVar = 12345;

const globalResetJob = schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 * * *', () => {
  yourVar = 1;
});
```